# "Save failed with the following error:" after overriding SAVE() - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I have overridden the Joomla save() function for some reason.

Last statement of the function is `return $data->player_id;` which get to the same form loaded with data from DB (That's good!)

Problem is that It shows

```
Save failed with the following error:
```

Message even every data field is saved correctly.

Here is the snippet

```
public function save($data) {

    $table_one = $this->getTable('Player', 'footballTable', array());
    // Bind the data.
    $table_one->bind($data);
    // Store the data.
    $table_one->save($data);

    // Some code here...

    return $data->player_id;
}
```

Comment: what was their old function returning? it's probably expecting a different return, just guessing though based on what you said.

Comment: I have not seen their code but what that does is loads the form with data upon saving the changes and displays the message "save successful"

Answer (score 1):

at the end of file write this one line:

```
return true;
```

for more information follow [this link](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-handle-save-failed-with-the-following-error-when-there-is-no-error).